# Avoiding BigInteger class/large numbers in arithmetic

Tags: java

I'm performing some mod arithmetic type stuff on a string where each char gets a certain initial value(depending on its ascii) and position in the string. these numbers get quite large as their initial value is `(ascii)*26^charPos`. It's worth noting that numerical characters only add their value(0-9) to the total;

Is there a way to avoid using the BigInt class(as I'm only interested in the `(intialVal)%(relatively small number))` I suppose you could use the usual:

```
value += val;
  if(value >= mod)
   value = value % mod;
```

But this would only work in a sorted list of integers and also would not solve the problem of when a single character generates a BigInt by using the above formula for character value. I'm sure something could be done in place with the mod operator.

As an aside;
the arithmetic won't turn out properly if bigNum exceeds the size of a long(or int, whatever foo is as declared as) right?

```
int(or long) foo = BigNum(possibly bigger than long) % smallMod;
```

I realize I could declare several BigInteger objects and just add all values to a totalValue and then perform the final mod operation on the total, but I'd rather avoid that if possible as BigInteger arithmetic is something I haven't used much(and it just seems like a pain the ass and generally unnecessary in this case). I know there'll be many approaches, but I wouldn't mind hearing some different perspectives. thanks in advance.

Here's some code I came up with that works whenever the long threshold is not broken;

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String str = "st4ck0ver";

    char[] x = str.toCharArray();
    long value = 0;
    int mod = 87;

    for(int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {

        long val;
        int charVal;
        int exp = x.length - (i+1);

        if((int)x[i] < 58) {
            charVal = (int)x[i] - 48;
            val = charVal;
        }
        else{
            charVal = (int)x[i]- 96;
            val = (long) (charVal * Math.pow(26, exp));
        }

        value += val;

        System.out.println("exp:" + exp + ",  char:" + x[i] + ", "
                + ",  charValue:" + charVal + " value:" + val + ",  curr total value:" + value);
    }
    value %= mod;
    System.out.println("Final value:" + value); 
}
```

---

**EDIT:** In response to David Wallace's answer:

I'm sorry, I reread your explanation and I do understand what you're doing... Your answer was precisely what I was getting at. I'm just having trouble dealing with the case when the character is a number as it only adds the numerical value instead of multiplying it by `26^pos`. I've kept a running total for the numerical values in order to add it to the final answer(as well as modding it again if it exceeds the mod value) but I can't figure out how to increase the appropriate power by one as well. I'm probably missing something quite obvious. The commented code is my half attempt at solving this problem:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //String str = "st4ck0ver";
    //String str = "hello";
    String str = "time2go";

    char[] x = str.toCharArray();
    int mod = 2004;

    int answer = 0;
    int power = 1;
    int numericalVal = 0;
    //int skipPower;

    for (int i = x.length - 1; i >=0; i--) {
        int charVal;

        if((int)x[i] < 58)  {
            charVal = (int)x[i] - 48;
            numericalVal += charVal;
            //skipPower++; //perhaps need to use something like this?
                //
        }       //      down
        else {  //   in here somewhere
            charVal = (int)x[i]- 96;

            answer += ( charVal * power);
            answer %= mod;
            power *= 26;
            power %= mod;
            //skipPower = 0; //reset skipPower in case it was used
        }
    }
    //answer += numericalVal;
    //if(answer + numericalVal >= mod)
    //  answer %= mod;

    System.out.println("Final value:" + answer);    
}
```

Comment: Your question is quite unclear !!!!

Comment: I agree that your question is unclear.  But if you're trying to figure out how to perform a `%` operation on an integer that is too big for a `long`, I suggest you stick with `BigInteger`, unless `smallMod` is a power of 2.  Division and `%` on indefinite-size integers are pretty hard to implement yourself, and I'm pretty sure the people who implemented `BigInteger` have put a lot of effort and research into developing the best algorithms to do the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're doing this in a certain modulus, then iterate through your `String`, keeping track of a running total of your required value in that modulus, and the value of the appropriate power of 26, also in that modulus.  If the modulus is very small, as you state, then an `int` should be adequate for each of these.

Note that I've assumed that your `String` consists only of lower case letters here.  Fix this up if you need to.

```
int answer = 0;
int power = 1;

for (int i = 0; i < inputString.length(); i++) {
    int charValue = inputString.charAt(i) - 'a';
    answer += ( charValue * power );
    answer %= mod;
    power *= 26;
    power %= mod;
}
```

**Edit**

Accommodating the OP's edits, which show that the `String` must be traversed in reverse order, and that place value is not taken into account when a digit is encountered, the code should probably be as follows.

```
int answer = 0;
int power = 1;

for (int i = inputString.length() - 1; i >=0; i--) {

    if(inputString.charAt( i ) < 58)  {
        int charValue  = inputString.charAt( i ) - 48;
        answer += charValue;
    }       
    else {  
        int charValue  = inputString.charAt( i ) - 96;
        answer += ( charValue * power );
    }

    answer %= mod;
    power *= 26;
    power %= mod;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the response. the problem occurs when the initial value of one of the chars in the string(occurs in long strings) exceeds long. (and i realize i didnt need the array, but i was performing something similiar with integers earlier and did not change it.)

Comment: How can the value of a `char` exceed the size of a `long`?

Comment: i mean the value that that specific character generates based on its place in the string and its position in the alphabet.                                                   value = (posInAlpha)(26^posInString).                                i cannot modify the value formula

Comment: But you said in the question that you're adding it all up in a particular small-valued modulus; and in your example code, that modulus was 87.  Unless that modulus gets close to the size of an `int`, then my approach will work fine.  The REAL value of `26^posInString` is irrelevant if you have the value of `26^posInString` in the desired modulus.

Comment: i doubt my modulus will exceed 200. but im still unsure of how your approach works.. your approach is exactly what i was asking about but i dont quite understand about carrying the modulus. this last sentence  "The REAL value of 26^posInString is irrelevant if you have the value of 26^posInString in the desired modulus" is great but i dont see how your code accomplishes that.

Comment: Because each time through the loop, I multiply `power` by 26.  So let's say the modulus is 87.  The first time through, I'm taking the character at position 0 and multiplying its value by 1.  The second time through, I'm taking the character at position 1 and multiplying its value by 26.  The third time through, I'm taking the character at position 2 and multiplying its value by 67 (which is 26^2 mod 87).  And so on.

Comment: i edidted my previous post with some more code. i just cant figure out how  to incorporate the numerical character case, without throwing off the rhythm of your your cool method.

Comment: OK, I've looked at your updates.  it looks like  you're 95% of the way there.  I'll post my own update in a little while, to take you the last 5%.

Comment: yep! that's it. thank you david. clean and efficient way of dealing with potentially large numbers in mod arithmetic.

Comment: i just came across this approach in a textbook i had on my computer. ha well at least now its burned into my brain.

Answer (score 0):

If the result of:

```
long longVal = new BigInteger(stringVal).mod(new BigInteger(modulus)).longValue();
```

is too big to fit in a `long` you will encounter the following behaviour, quoting the [BigInteger#longValue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#longValue()) method in the JDK:

> If this BigInteger is too big to fit in a long, only the low-order 64 bits are returned. Note that this conversion can lose information about the overall magnitude of the BigInteger value as well as return a result with the opposite sign.

So you're right in thinking if you try to get a `long` value from a `BigInteger` bigger than a `long` you will not get an accurate result.